# Prevent bootstrap 3 from resetting nested grids / use master grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to make Bootstrap 3 use just my outer grid columns?

For example, I've built Bootstrap to use 10 columns instead of 12.  I've divided my layout to have a 2 column left div and an 8 column right div.

My main content goes in the right.  I want to divide the main content into four equal columns, which should just be four .col-md-2 elements.  Bootstrap however wants to reset the grid back to ten when I place .col elements into the right div.

Help?

Comment: The problem is likely because you're trying to divide your main content (which is inside a col-~~-8) by 4 using col-~~-2 when you need to use col-~~-3.  Could you post some of your markup pelase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the outer column is 8 and 2 = 10 but you want 4 equal inside the main content which should equal 10, but instead you have col-md-2 x 4 = 8 so you can't do that you need to have that add to 10 inside that main content. You'll need use columns that are 25% in width, if you converted correctly to use 10 columns then it's probably col-md-4.

You need to post a fiddle or a bootply to get better answers. Or switch back to 12 columns and fiddle with the widths of those columns in LESS (less painful).

Comment: Yeah, that's my question:  is it possible to get bootstrap to use only the outer container for grid widths, essentially "remembering" that my right div is 8 wide so I can divide it evenly into 4 columns?  Or will bootstrap always reset nested divs back to the defined 10 columns?

Comment: all grids work this way the width of anything is 100%, so you stick a 2 col layout and then either one of those columns if you nest then it's back to 100% so you start again.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured :/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, and just replied to a similar question - I think there's no way of making it with Bootstrap itself, because the grid system is all CSS. However, I coded a piece of Javascript to calculate the percentages according to the nesting level - it seems to work ok here. Here's the gist:
https://gist.github.com/royalsflush/8422780

Here's the bootply with the script: http://bootply.com/105852

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom bootstrap without the grid system, you can get it by unchecking the "GRID SYSTEM" and downloading the custom content at the end of the page.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/